# extract and load from mysql DB to another

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

I would like to extract and load data from mysql DB to another mysql DB without shutting down mysql in the process.

Tried to use the open source Talend community edition.
Used mysql input component, filled connection details which were tested to work.

Component could not connect to mysql and got the error:

```
Exception in component tMysqlOutput_1
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

though I added to eclipse project the jar: **`mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar`**

Comment: Is your objective to use Telend or is it to copy the database?

Comment: What OS are you using, also which version of talend? Are the mysql databases located on the local host, on the local network, or on the internet such as in Amazon EC2 or RDS? Tell us more about the environment.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql components in talend should absolutely work out of the box without the need to load any additional drivers. I'd say reinstall talend because something else is wrong.

To manually load your mysql connector, you can use the tLibraryLoad component.
Choose the jar file from the dropdown in the "Basic Settings". It should be there if it's been included in the project.
You can also pick a lib path in the component's advanced settings and add the import line below that.

Again, you certainly shouldn't need to do this for the mysql component. Talend comes with the drivers to connect to all databases that have components.
In fact I've copied those drivers to other programs that didn't come with them.

Good luck!